# How to reset or "un-initialize" vault?

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to automate vault v0.8.0 deployment (vaultproject from Hashicorp) with a consul v0.9.1 backend.

Because it is a trial and error process I need to run "vault init" a couple of times (until I get it right) and get the keys.

Unfortunately I lost the keys and the root token.

I tried to stop vault and consul service - nothing
"* Vault is already initialized" and "* Vault is sealed"

I stopped vault, removed the vault path from consul, started vault - same result - and at "vault init" I receive this error:

```
* expiration state restore failed: failed to scan for leases: list failed at path '': Unexpected response code: 403
```

and it's creating the vault/ path again in consul and remain sealed.

How can I "reset" vault or make it UN-initialized and start over with "vault init" ?

This is the log:

```
Aug 10 05:01:49 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: ==> Vault server started! Log data will stream in below:
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.238436 [INFO ] core: security barrier not initialized
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.271844 [INFO ] core: security barrier initialized: shares=5 threshold=3
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.320363 [INFO ] core: post-unseal setup starting
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.342931 [INFO ] core: loaded wrapping token key
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.356895 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=generic path=secret/
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.357342 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=cubbyhole path=cubbyhole/
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.357736 [INFO ] core: successfully mounted backend: type=system path=sys/
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.358293 [INFO ] rollback: starting rollback manager
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.381808 [INFO ] expiration: restoring leases
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.383943 [INFO ] core: pre-seal teardown starting
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.384154 [INFO ] core: cluster listeners not running
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.384365 [INFO ] rollback: stopping rollback manager
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.384633 [INFO ] core: pre-seal teardown complete
Aug 10 05:03:26 TSLASOWROMM01 vault[9156]: 2017/08/10 05:03:26.384909 [ERROR] core: post-unseal setup failed during init: error=expiration state restore failed: failed to scan for leases: list failed at path '': Unexpected response code: 403
```

Comment: The answers below cover Consul and File backends. Anyone have a take on "Integrated Storage" aka "Raft"? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the discussion of this same question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vault-tool/xuO8IInubDg/SBHMP2PKAwAJ, the answer is:

> Vault is storing its state in Consul, so if you shut down Vault and delete Vault's key prefix in Consul things should start clean again.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone reads this post with the same intention as I did -> looking for "file"-backend or "database"-backend

**file backend:**

If you look into the vault configuration file (e.g. `/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl`)

There is a directive `storage "file" { path = "/some/file/name" ......`

Just empty the directory `/some/file/name` (do not remove, just emtpy).

**database backend:**

you just have to `truncate` the "vault_kv_store" table and restart vault:

```
psql -U myvaultdbuser -h myvaultDB.host.name -p5432 vaultdatabasname -c 'truncate table vault_kv_store';
```

**... and to initialize again:**

Then direct your Browser to e.g. `http://localhost:8820/ui/vault/init` to initialize it again

Answer (score 4):

With any storage backend of Vault you should be able to just delete your storage. Looks like you were running into an bug with that older version of Consul.

Answer (score 0):

If Vault was installed with helm with no modifications, it creates a `PersistentVolume` to store the data. You can delete these volumes in a development environment (Note this will delete all your secrets too)

```
kubectl get pvc -A
kubectl [-n NAMESPACE] delete pvc <VAULT-PVC-NAME>

kubectl get pv -A
kubectl [-n NAMESPACE] delete pv <VAULT-PV-NAME>
```

Answer (score -1):

With vault version Vault v1.7.3. I noticed it created a folder vault-data and I had to rename it to un-initialize.